# The Lufthansa Lottery

Tags: mathematics, no-computers, combinatorics

In order to pass free time while striking for better pay, some Lufthansa workers organise a lottery where

- each ticket picks three distinct numbers from $1$ to $11$ inclusive
- the draw picks **five** distinct numbers from $1$ to $11$ inclusive
- a ticket wins iff **all** its numbers were drawn.

Prove *without computers* that $33$ tickets are sufficient to guarantee a win.

Comment: Via integer linear programming, the minimum turns out to be rot13(gjragl avar).

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. Did you have a particular 33-ticket solution in mind?

Comment: @RobPratt My $33$-ticket solution was all cyclic shifts of (1,2,3), (1,4,7) and (1,3,7). I was inspired to write this puzzle by [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4500748/bounding-tur%c3%a1n-numbers-t-311-5-and-t-316-7).

Comment: Because of this HNQ, I became aware that Lufthansa workers were striking. See, covert advertising does work!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's a simple way to guarantee a win with

> 30 tickets.

Partition $\{1,\dots,11\}$ into $A=\{1,\dots,6\}$ and $B=\{7,\dots,11\}$.  By the pigeonhole principle, every draw of $5$ numbers must contain at least $\lceil5/2\rceil=3$ numbers in either $A$ or $B$.  So buy

> $$\binom{|A|}{3}+\binom{|B|}{3}=\binom{6}{3}+\binom{5}{3} = 20 + 10 = 30$$

tickets.

Comment: This method is quite brilliant! The solution isn't quite symmetrical though, so it stands to reason there might be enough wiggle room to shave off another ticket somehow..

Comment: @Bass thanks.  Indeed, exactly one ticket (see my rot13 comment).

Comment: Is it common in real-world lotteries to be able to buy specific tickets? As I understand it, your solution is to buy all A-only and all B-only tickets, but how would you make sure you don't get any A/B mixed ticket when you just pick 30 tickets from the ticket box?

Comment: @MichaelKarcher You can choose your own numbers.  For example, many people like to pick numbers based on birthdays of family members.

Comment: Thanks for the nudge, I get it now. I was focussed on games like a scratch-card lottery or a raffle where there are pre-printed numbers. Even the german "pick-your-own-numbers" state lottery has at least one side-game that depends on a ticket number you can't influence.

Comment: @MichaelKarcher From the US here, we have things like PowerBall, MegaMillions, state lotteries, etc, where all the numbers can be chosen by the buyer (or you can Quick Pick some or all of the numbers, and the computer decide). The current MegaMillions, coincidentally, is sitting with a jackpot of $1.28 billion USD.